# Is it Possible to get every disk or LUN sd{a,b,c,d} that a mountpoint "/main" was created on? not lvm or vg but the disk itself. Ansible or script

Tags: python, linux, bash, ansible, centos

So I need help with this, I want to find every multipathed disk or LUN /main resides on i.e sd[a,b,c,d] then put the results in a file.

```
sda                               8:0    0 893.3G  0 disk
├─sda1                            8:1    0   300M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─sda2                            8:2    0     1G  0 part  /boot
└─sda3                            8:3    0   892G  0 part
  ├─VolGroup00-root             253:0    0   888G  0 lvm   /
  └─VolGroup00-swap             253:1    0     4G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
sdb                               8:16   0     3T  0 disk
└─NS2FPPRMDB08_MongoDB_Data     253:2    0     3T  0 mpath
  └─mongo_data_vg-mongo_data_lv 253:3    0     3T  0 lvm   /main
sdc                               8:32   0     3T  0 disk
└─NS2FPPRMDB08_MongoDB_Data     253:2    0     3T  0 mpath
  └─mongo_data_vg-mongo_data_lv 253:3    0     3T  0 lvm   /main
sdd                               8:48   0     3T  0 disk
└─NS2FPPRMDB08_MongoDB_Data     253:2    0     3T  0 mpath
  └─mongo_data_vg-mongo_data_lv 253:3    0     3T  0 lvm   /main
sde                               8:64   0     3T  0 disk
└─NS2FPPRMDB08_MongoDB_Data     253:2    0     3T  0 mpath
  └─mongo_data_vg-mongo_data_lv 253:3    0     3T  0 lvm   /main
```

I did it with Ansible but shows only one device if there's more than 1 device used for /main .

```
---
  - name: 
    hosts: dba
    vars:
        dev_name: '{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]["facter_mountpoints"]["/data"]["device"]| basename}}'
    tasks:
      - name: get device name
        set_fact:
          device_name: "{{ item.key }}"
        no_log: false
        with_dict: "{{ ansible_devices }}"
        when:  " dev_name in  item.value.holders"

      - name: show all values for selected device name
        debug:
          var: "{{ item }}"
        with_items:
           ansible_devices[device_name]

      - name: show only device name
        debug: var=device_name
```

Answer (score 0):

`lsblk -lpo mountpoint,pkname,kname,name,path | grep '/main '`

run `lsblk -lpO` and decide what fields you want to output.